# Hook menu - title arguments

Tags: routes, hooks

I have those menu elements declared in hook_menu function:

```
$items['submission/%/id/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'View submission',
    'title callback' => 'fr_form_view_submission_page_title',
    'title arguments' => array(3),
    'page arguments' => array(1, 3),
    'page callback' => 'fr_form_node_object_id',
    'access arguments' => array('content access'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'weight' => 100,
  );

  $items['submission/%/id/%/view'] = array(
    'title' => 'View submission',
    'title callback' => 'fr_form_view_submission_page_title',
    'title arguments' => array(3),
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );

  $items['submission/%/id/%/edit'] = array(
    'title' => 'Edit submission',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 3, 4),
    'page callback' => 'fr_form_node_object_id',
    'title callback' => 'fr_form_edit_submission_page_title',
    'title arguments' => array(3),
    'access arguments' => array('content access'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 100,
  );
```

As you can see the first menu item has a fr_form_view_submission_page_title() function to set the title. And the function looks like this:

```
function fr_form_view_submission_page_title($id) {
  return t('View submission ID: @id', array('@id' => $id));
}
```

Second item makes the first one default.

Third menu item has a title callback function which looks like this:

```
function fr_form_edit_submission_page_title($id) {
  return t('Edit submission ID: @id', array('@id' => $id));
}
```

**When I go to page /submission/10/id/1** I get the result. Two tabs next to each other with text on it:

first tab: View submission ID: 1
second tab: Edit submission ID: 1

And the page title is: View submission ID: 1

**And if I go to the edit tab (/submission/10/id/1/edit)** I get exacly the same, so:

first tab: View submission ID: 1
second tab: Edit submission ID: 1

And the page title is: View submission ID: 1

**What I want to achive is to have tabs always signed:**

first tab: View submission

second tab: Edit submission

And the page title depending on path, so for /submission/10/id/1 I should get:
View submission ID: 1

And for /submission/10/id/1/edit I should get:
Edit submission ID: 1

Comment: Hi, David. Hopefully someone else can confirm but I don't think it's currently possible to set a different page title using `hook_menu()`. You may have to `drupal_set_title()` inside your page callback instead, perhaps retrieving your arguments from `$_GET['q']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single title callback by passing two arguments :

```
'title arguments' => array(3, 4),
```

and use same callback for both function :

```
function fr_form_view_submission_page_title($id, $type = 'view') {
  $type = ucfirst($type);
  return t('@type submission ID: @id', array('@type' => $type, '@id' => $id));
}
```